# VBA + PowerPoint: iterate over text in textboxes doesn't seem to find text by color

Tags: vba, automation, powerpoint, object-model

I have to do a search and replace on certain colors in my PowerPoint slides. Long story and I'm not allowed to change the template color schemes.

I found this VBA script http://skp.mvps.org/pptxp006.htm and it works great on lines/fill in PPT graphics. But it doesn't seem to handle the text properly.

The general approach of this VBA script is:

```
For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
        If oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
        For I = 1 To oShp.GroupItems.Count
                [[ do something to oShp.GroupItems(i) ]]
            Next I
        Else
            [[ do something to oShp ]]        
    End If
    Next oShp
Next oSld
```

and the "do something" includes a call to `FindAndReColourText()`:

```
Function FindAndReColourText(oShp As Shape, _
    oRGB As Long, oNewRGB As Long)
Dim I As Integer
Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
On Error Resume Next
If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
    If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
        Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange            
        For I = 1 To oTxtRng.Runs.Count
            With oTxtRng.Runs(I).Font.Color                    
                If .Type = msoColorTypeRGB Then                       
                    If .rgb = oRGB Then
                        .rgb = oNewRGB
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next I
    End If
End If
End Function
```

I've checked and it does seem to iterate through text but it's not matching the color somehow. Any suggestions on how I should debug?

(I don't really know where to look to find this out and someone dumped this task on me quickly with dozens of slides I need to change.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha -- the problem was that it wasn't working for text that uses template colors; the `.Type = msoColorTypeRGB` test wasn't matching.

```
If .Type = msoColorTypeRGB Then                       
   If .rgb = oRGB Then
         .rgb = oNewRGB
   End If
End If
```

I removed this outer `If` and it worked properly.